# losing data when transfering SqlDataReader object to the method that needs IDataReader interface

Tags: c#, casting, sqldatareader, idatareader

I have a method which needs a SqlDataReader object as parameter, and i have tests where i've mocked that object, and everything worked fine.

But, now i need to change that method. It should now only call new method, which has a IDataReader as parameter, and thats a problem, because, when I'm transfering the mocked SqlDataReader as a parameter of new method, it's losing his data, and i don't know why.

Something like this:

```
void method(SqlDataReader mockedObject)
{
   // example property
   mockedObject.FieldCount; // for example the value is 1;
   newMethod(mockedObject);
}

void newMethod(IDataReader newObject)
{
   // example property
   newObject.FieldCount // here value is 0;
}
```

I observed that if i'm only copying the SqlDataReader object to the new variable of type IDataReader, data also are cleared.

Something like this:

```
void method(SqlDataReader mockedObject)
{
   IDataReader variable = mockedObject;
}
```

the proper code:

```
=========================================================================================
        [TestMethod()]
    [DeploymentItem("IICMS.dll")]
    public void CheckNullableDateTimeTest_SqlDataReader_Valid()
    {
        MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
        SqlDataReader reader = mocks.DynamicMock<SqlDataReader>();
        string column = "test";
        DateTime? expected = new DateTime(2, 1, 1);
        Nullable<DateTime> actual;

        reader.Stub(r => r[column]).Return(expected);
        reader.Stub(r => r.FieldCount).Return(1);
        mocks.ReplayAll();

        actual = Utility_Accessor.CheckNullableDateTime(reader, column);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
======================================================================================
        public static DateTime? CheckNullableDateTime(SqlDataReader read, string column)
    {
        return GetValue<DateTime?>(read, column, null);
    }
======================================================================================
public static T GetValue<T>(IDataReader reader, string columnName, T defaultValue)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (reader.GetName(i) == columnName)
                {
                    object value = reader[i];
                    return Convert.IsDBNull(value) ? defaultValue : (T)value;
                }
            }

            return defaultValue;
        }
        catch
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }
```

So there's the code, the second and the third method are in other dll but it doesn't have impact on anything. Object are mocked in RhinoMocks ;)

Data are losing after transfering SqlDataReader object (read) to GetValue method (i.e. FieldCount equals 0, in Check.. method it has proper value = 1)

Comment: So.. does this mean that if you call `FieldCount` twice (even in the same method) you get two different results, 1 and then 0?

Comment: If not, is `FieldCount` overriden with the `new` keyword?

Comment: Note that you're not actually copying the object, you're just converting the reference, there's nothing going on, as `SqlDataReader` doesn't have any explicit or implicit conversion operators.

Comment: @casperOne ok, but IDataReader is a interface, and SqlDataReader implements it, so i should be able to do transfer it to the second method, without losing my data (i.e. FieldCount parameter)
[/br]
Patrick : if you call it twice, the value will be the same, but if you try to put? reader into new IDataReader object and then call this property, it will be diffrent

Comment: I don't disagree with that, but just making it clear that there's no copying to a new object or anything of that sort.

Comment: Is SqlDataReader the one from System.Data or your own mocked class? Is the issue still there if you type `((IDataReader)mockedObject).FieldCount`?

Comment: ok i get it, thanks for answer, but i'm still in ... :)

@Patrick I will check it ;)
So i checked, and after that the value is changed (loosed)

Comment: @user1732439: And you're using the SqlDataReader from the System.Data namespace?

Comment: @morel: That's not what I asked..

Comment: @Patrick: It's System.Data.SqlClient namespace, so it's what are you asked for ;)

Comment: I'm a dufus.. Hm, well. Then you need to show us the code you're using to create and pass in the reader to `method`, based on what you have in your question right now I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @Patrick I've edited the post, so you can check the whole code

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain this but changing test method to the form below, makes, that
all object fields are aviable in each method (CheckNullString and GetValue):

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [DeploymentItem("IICMS.dll")]
    public void CheckNullableDateTimeTest_SqlDataReader_Valid()
    {
        MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
        SqlDataReader reader = mocks.DynamicMock<SqlDataReader>();
        IDataReader reader2 = reader;
        string column = "test";
        DateTime? expected = new DateTime(2,1,1);
        DateTime? actual;

        reader.Stub(r => r[column]).Return(invalidValue);
        reader.Stub(r => r[0]).Return(invalidValue);
        reader.Stub(r => r.FieldCount).Return(1);
        reader.Stub(r => r.GetName(0)).Return(column);

        reader2.Stub(r => r[column]).Return(invalidValue);
        reader2.Stub(r => r[0]).Return(invalidValue);
        reader2.Stub(r => r.FieldCount).Return(1);
        reader2.Stub(r => r.GetName(0)).Return(column);
        mocks.ReplayAll();

        actual = Utility_Accessor.CheckNullString(reader, column);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```